# Crash UICollectionViewFlowLayout when applying snapshot on iOS 15

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uicollectionviewflowlayout, uicollectionviewdiffabledatasource

I have a `UICollectionView` with a simple `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`. On iOS 15 when first loading the view and setting the items an exception occurs.

This is called on the main thread when the items are set:

```
var snapshot = NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot<Section, PageItem>()
snapshot.appendSections([.main])
snapshot.appendItems(filteredPages)
dataSource.apply(snapshot, animatingDifferences: true)
```

I'm getting the following exception:

```
'the invalidation context ((null)) sent to -[UICollectionViewFlowLayout invalidateLayoutWithContext:] is not an instance of type UICollectionViewFlowLayoutInvalidationContext or a subclass'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Running the same project on iOS 14 does not crash.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is animating the change, so change from:

```
dataSource.apply(snapshot, animatingDifferences: true)
```

to

```
dataSource.apply(snapshot, animatingDifferences: false)
```